# Python, os.system and subprocess.call both don't work for variable string command

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I'm trying to issue a command to another application using python, but it seems to only acknowledge part of the command. Here are the lines of code in question:

```
command = 'potreeconverter {} -q NICE -p {} –o {}\{}\{}\{}'.format(path,folder,pathup[0],cid,wpid,folder)
print (command)
os.system(command)
```

I'm fairly new to Python so forgive me if that's a weird way to construct a string for a directory name containing many variables. However, the print function always returns the exact command that I intended, and it will run as intended if I simply copy and paste it into the command prompt manually.

```
potreeconverter C:\Users\thomas\source\test.las -q NICE -p test –o C:\Users\thomas\source\55555\55555\test
```

The command is accepted by the application, but it ignores the -o parameter, which specifies an output directory for the application. It does the same thing if I use subprocess.call. No other part of the command is ever ignored.

I read that this issue can be solved by having python write the command to a batch file, and then sending the batch file through. I would really rather not do that because it would be pretty inefficient. Is there another way that anyone knows of to avoid this?

Also, I'm unsure what this means but I thought it was odd and perhaps significant. When this problem occurs, and only when this problem occurs, the default output directory that the program chooses instead of the one I specified will use forward slashes instead of backslashes.

Comment: What is the returned value from `os.system()`?

Comment: I set the command to a variable and printed it, and it returned 0

Comment: If it is returning zero then it appears to have working.  You need to look at `potreeconverter`, for example, do you have more than one version?  Does `potreeconverter` accept file paths with a \ directory separator?  `/` works on Windows by the way, that might be worth a stab.

Comment: Yes, a forward slash does work on windows for the most part, except in some older programs I believe. I would try that, and also make sure that there are no possibly different versions of potreeconverter around, which python may be seeing first, but are incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure I don't leave everyone hanging, I figured out the solution. It's very strange. All I did was call the parameters in a different order, and now it works every time. They work in any order if I input the command manually, but if I issue the command from python it seems it will only work if I write the output parameter first. Not sure if this is a problem with python or with the application I'm writing the command to.

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape your backslashes.
a backslash is a special character, and that is why you are able to encode special characters like tabs (`\t`), newlines (`\n`) and a bunch more.
so you could just replace this:

```
command = 'potreeconverter {} -q NICE -p {} –o {}\{}\{}\{}'.format(path,folder,pathup[0],cid,wpid,folder)
```

with:

```
command = 'potreeconverter {} -q NICE -p {} –o {}\\{}\\{}\\{}'.format(path,folder,pathup[0],cid,wpid,folder)
```

you could also use python's [raw string notation](https://knowledge.kitchen/Raw_strings_in_Python#The_solution:_raw_strings), which I, personally consider nicer, and easier to maintain:

```
command = r'potreeconverter {} -q NICE -p {} –o {}\{}\{}\{}'.format(path,folder,pathup[0],cid,wpid,folder)
```

what this does is it simply tells python not to count *any* character as special (except for format strings, but that kind of doesn't count).
now, as to what you said about it being a strange way to make paths, there is a better way, which is `os.path.join`. this takes any arguments, and joins them as a path. for example it would do:

```
>>> os.path.join('C:\\tuna', 'fish', 'directory')
'C:\\tuna\\fish\\directory'
>>>
```

there are 3 major advantages here: it will choose between `/` or `\` depending on the system (`\` on windows\DOS, `/` on Unix/Linux, etc...), it can take any amount of arguments, and is more readable. in your case, you could do:

```
import os.path

base = 'potreeconverter {} -q NICE -p {} –o'
path = os.path.join(pathup[0], cid, wpid, folder)
command = ' '.join((base, path))
```

your code would work too, but this is the recommended way for working with paths.
if you have any questions, please ask. have a good day!

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the super comprehensive answer! But actually all of those methods give the same result I was already having. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: no, I have no idea, thats very strange. if you can, could you post the entire code or a minimal, runable example, so i can try it?

Comment: can i see what you get when you call `print(command)` and maybe try writing it to a file too, to see how it is encoded then?

Comment: Before I take the time to do that, after thinking about it for a bit I think I might know what's causing it. I'm on Windows. Do you think the fact that I'm using python instead of a Windows command shell could fool an application into thinking it isn't being run on a Windows computer, and that might cause this problem? The output directory it defaults to is written in the Unix/Linux format, but only when I issue the command through python.

Comment: That seems unlikely, but maybe possible if you are on something like cygwin, but I don't know

Comment: This answer was my first thought too, but some experimentation proved that not to be the case (I thought that the `{` was escaped).

Comment: are there possibly any other executable files on the path where it could be searching? because perhaps if it finds a `potreeconverter.cmd` or `potreeconverter.js`, or `potreeconverter.(anything on PATHTEXT)` that it could be calling instead, i dont know